# Trading Lot Size Number of Shares to Buy / Dollars per x-action / Shares per x-action

Tags: trading

Trying to figure out an average amount of dollars per "buy" transaction that would be most efficient, and leave me less prone to being taken advantage of by high-frequency-traders. For example, let's say I want to buy $50K of Apple stock; should I buy it in chunks of $5k or all $50k at once? Question assumes we're talking about big-well-known-company like Apple, and purchase entity is a small retail investor using Fidelity, Scottrade, Schwab, etc.

Comment: How would a high-frequency-trader take advantage of you in this scenario?

Comment: @DanielCarson that was the question I was going to ask.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, as a retail trader, you shouldn't pay too much attention to this. HFT do profit on scalping you for a few pennies more however just place in a limit order and you should be fine. The market will fluctuate enough in the intraday or long term to get a price you want.

But if you are concerned, buy in smaller blocks. However the downside is higher commission fees. I'd also look into how your order is routed once place with your brokerage. Some brokerages sell rights to HFT firms to route their clients orders to them then to the exchange.

By the way, 50k of Apple at the current market price is nothing (~300 shares) to be worried about. I'd be worried if you are buying 100k+ blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your commission schedule, whether it's per share or fixed sum, in the former case it would be beneficial to spread the order into smaller ones because the smart market participants will judge your small orders to have lesser impact and therefore you won't be taken advantage of as much.
There is evidence to suggest routing your orders to IEX is beneficial (if your broker allows this), especially if your order is marketable.